# pip install connection not establishing

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda

I am running pip install and anything I try to install max retries out. I am on windows 10 and using Anaconda which had pip installed from the onset. I recently ran git clean by accident and messed up my files, this may have something to do with the pip install problem. pip install does work with .whl files so i think the problem lies in the connection but what i have tried so far has yielded little change.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003763DA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pypdf2/      
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000037639B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pypdf2/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003763898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pypdf2/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000037637F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pypdf2/      
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003763F60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pypdf2/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyPDF2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyPDF2
```

Thanks in advance, up to this point i have just downloading every package off the internet and that is a real pain, so if this could be fixed that would be great!

Comment: Are you running the command with admin privileges?